# Print jQuery dialog using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, printing

Is there a way, using the print css file, to cause a hidden jquery dialog to print? I would like the user to be able to simply choose print from the browser, but I need the printout to include a closed jquery dialog. The printing .css works for all the other formatting/hiding/etc I need to do to produce a "decent" printout, but I can't seem to get the closed jquery dialog to reappear using this .css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override the inline style placed by jQuery with the `[style]` selector and `!important`, as described here: http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

```
div[style] {
   display: visible !important;//override jQuery hidden with visible
}
```

Comment: The !important was what I was missing. Thanks!